# How to convert many to many field to foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say I have a model class like;

```
class SamplingQuery(models.Model):
   brands = models.ManyToManyField(Brand)
```

After a while I realize that I need to convert ManyToManyField to ForeignKey so I need to convert this class to a ForeignKey;

```
class SamplingQuery(models.Model):
   brands = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
```

Is there a way to do it without losing any data?

Thank you

Comment: Well that depends on the data you have; do you have anything where there are many brands to a samplingquery?

Comment: No, all queries have only one brand now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple mechanism, but you can always do the following:

1. Create a new `ForeignKey` (say, `brand`)
2. Copy existing data from `brands` (by slicing the first result since there can be multiple with a `ManyToMany` relation) to `brand`
3. Delete the field `brands`